# Mongoose reference on custom string _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I created a schema with a custom _id (an example: `PIy8CvtO32a0DOvXv`) using a function that generates a random string. I can create and edit my documents perfectly.

Then, I tried referencing a document of this schema in another one but i keep getting this error `integration references a non existing ID` when i try to create a document in this collection. This error pops normally when the the provided _id doesn't match any document in your collection but I checked and found a document with this _id. Is there something i'm missing out or is there any restriction related to my custom string _id ?
Below is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ObjectID } = require('mongodb');
const idValidator = require('mongoose-id-validator');

const integrationSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  { 
    _id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    provider: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    }
})
integrationSchema.plugin(idValidator);
const IntegrationSchema = mongoose.model('Integration', integrationSchema);
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ObjectID } = require('mongodb');
const idValidator = require('mongoose-id-validator');

const sourceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  integration: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    ref: 'Integration',
    refConditions: {
      active: true,
    },
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
sourceSchema.plugin(idValidator);
const SourceSchema = mongoose.model('Source', sourceSchema);
```

Comment: did the referenced integration document also has `active: true` field on it?

Comment: Yes it does, i just edited my post